# stuck at UDP response

Tags: c#, .net, udp

```
        public string GetUDP(string command = "")
        {
            string final = "Failed";
            udpClient.Connect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.10.1"), 8889));
            Byte[] sendBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(command);
            udpClient.Send(sendBytes, sendBytes.Length);
            IPEndPoint RemoteIpEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
            Byte[] receiveBytes = udpClient.Receive(ref RemoteIpEndPoint);
            final = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receiveBytes);
            return final;
        }
```

It will be stuck on `Byte[] receiveBytes = udpClient.Receive(ref RemoteIpEndPoint);`

The drone receives it because if i send TAKEOFF the drone takes off.

Here is the [drone documentation](https://terra-1-g.djicdn.com/2d4dce68897a46b19fc717f3576b7c6a/Tello%20%E7%BC%96%E7%A8%8B%E7%9B%B8%E5%85%B3/For%20Tello/Tello%20SDK%20Documentation%20EN_1.3_1122.pdf)

Comment: Fixed!
I do not know how my drone just decided to work

Comment: Also i had to use UTF8